# split data and save values using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have models:

```
class Web2Types(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Web2Domains(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    web2type = models.ForeignKey(Web2Types)
```

Now I have a string containing commas, I want that string first split by comma then all values of that list will save into `Web2Domains` model.

<------------------------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------------------------------------->

In Web2Types `name='social'`, `status=0` and assume it's auto incremented is 1.
In Web2Domains `domain='facebook.com'`, `web2type=1`

Now I want something like this in serializer:

```
webid = 1
domain_str = 'google.com,yahoo.com,stackoverflow.com,test.com'
domain_str_list = domain_str.split(',')
for domain1 in domain_str_list:
    Web2Domains.objects.create(domain=domain1, web2type=webid)
```

serializer:

```
class Web2DomainsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    web2type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Web2Domains
        fields = '__all__
```

'
This logic I want in Django rest framework serializer.

Comment: Give us some examples. What have you tried? What should save to Web2Domains and what to Web2Types?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov please see the question update.

Comment: @V.Khakhil it'd help if you showed your seralizier. You can do a little bit of work on the input and then have it `many=True` for instance

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I tried many=True but not getting how to implement above logic in serializer